# Ubuntu + Lampp and CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu, lampp

I'm trying execute `cake bake all` but doesn't works because I think the problem is with a path of my cake project. When I try execute the command on terminal does throws this exception: `Error: The datasource configuration "default" was not found in database.php`. The file database.php is in this path `ExemploCake/app/Config/database.php`.

I'm using: Ubuntu with Lampp and CakePHP 2.7

**Config database.php**

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'cakePHP',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'cakePHP',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
}
?>
```

**Exception**

```
    root@fernando-HP-15-Notebook-PC:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/app/Console# ./cake bake all

Welcome to CakePHP v2.7.0 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake All
---------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(105): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(952): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(889): ModelTask->getAllTables('default')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(979): ModelTask->listAll('default')
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/BakeShell.php(150): ModelTask->getName('default')
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(444): BakeShell->all()
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(212): Shell->runCommand('all', Array)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/app/Console/cake.php(47): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#9 {main}
```

Comment: install latest version of mysql in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Run `bake` from your `app` folder. So:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/ExemploCake/app
./Console/cake bake all
```

Edit based on updated post:

The error means you don't have pdo_mysql enabled for CLI. So find out the php.ini for CLI and enable it.

It seems you are using XAMPP. You will save yourself lot of trouble if you just use the packages provided my Ubuntu itself. You will find tons of tutorials for it on the net.

Comment: I edited the post. If I run `bake` from my app folder throws this exception: `Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.` but on browser it's all ok, look at: http://i.imgur.com/fx7CJBi.png